# Multiple deletion in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I used this in my view**

```
<form id="order" name="order" method="post" 
    action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Blog/multi_delete/">
```

**In controller I used**

```
function multi_delete()
{  
    $this->Blogmodel->multi_delete();
    redirect('blog/selectdata/show'); 
}
```

**In last in the model i used this**

```
function multi_delete()
{
    foreach($this->input->post(checkbox) as $check) 

    $this->db->where('id', $check);
    $this->db->delete('contactus'); 
}
```

The problem is that I cannot get value in controller when I click on delete its not access the controller

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the form helper function to let you build an error-proof form

```
ex. echo form_open ('blog/multi_delete');
```

and manage in multi_delete() method in blog controller the submission of post using, for example, the form_validation library.
ex

Or use `action="<?php echo site_url('blog/multi_delete');?`>"  to build a surely correct path.

Then make sure you're calling the right input fields in the model method (don't know if its a typo or waht, but you should use quotes `$this->input->post('checkbox')`.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'I cannot get value in controller', I assumed you loaded it wrong or you're not made us clear what you need to access there.

Comment: @Adil Abbasi If you have any problem, just ask. Anyway, if the answer solves your proble, you should mark it as 'accepted'. Thank you